# angular display table under navigation

Tags: angular, routes

I am trying to simply display a table based on the link a user clicks. I have already created the service to populate the table and the navigation tabs for the various tables. I am not quite sure how to get the table to display under the navigation tabs once the user clicks the tab.

I have cqi component in which the navigation tabs are created.

And I would like to display lcqi-dy component (where the smart table is being generated) under the navigation tab.

cqi-component.html

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" routerLink="../tables/lcqi-dy">LCQI Weekly</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">VCQI Weekly</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">3GCQI Weekly</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">LCQI Daily</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">VCQI VCQI Daily</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">3GCQI Daily</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

cqi component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cqi',
  templateUrl: './cqi.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cqi.component.scss']
})
export class CqiComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

[image]

pages routing module

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { PagesComponent } from './pages.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { CqiComponent } from './cqi/cqi.component';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './miscellaneous/not-found/not-found.component';


const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: PagesComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: 'dashboard',
      component: DashboardComponent,
    }, {
      path: 'cqi',
      component: CqiComponent,
    }, {
      path: 'tables',
      loadChildren: './tables/tables.module#TablesModule',
    },
    {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: 'dashboard',
      pathMatch: 'full',
    }, {
      path: '**',
      component: NotFoundComponent,
    }
  ],
}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class PagesRoutingModule {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As table is another module, you have to create separeta routing for it:

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { ParentComponent } from './parent.component';

export const tableRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: ParentComponent }, // path '.../tables'
      children: [
         {path: 'lcqi-dy', component: lcqi-dy-component-name} path '.../tables/lcqi-dy' 
];

export const tableRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(
    tableRoutes,
);
```

and In ParentComponent template you have to include `<router-outlet>`, where children from routing going to be rendered.

Also you have to import `tableRouting` in `TablesModule`